# Why is my app not available for all iPhones?

Tags: ios, iphone

After releasing an update to my app yesterday, I got a text from a friend saying iTunes wouldn't let him update because it said "The app is not compatible with this iPhone". He was on an iPhone 5c running latest iOS 9.1. I went and checked and it said this: 
[image: compatibility]

The app is not available to iPhones below iPhone 5S. I did not purposely change anything in the update for this to happen. Why is my app not available for all iPhones?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the list of devices, they all appear to have 64-bit CPUs – is it possible you accidentally disabled support for ARMv7? Did you modify Bitcode settings in the update, or change Xcode versions?

Answer (score 0):

The app is compiled for 64-bit only. You need to make sure you compile for both 32-bit and 64-bit architectures (armv7, armv7s, arm64). The best option is to use the default architecture settings.